# How to make visible a variable defined in index.html from a razor pages?

Tags: mapbox, blazor

I would like to make a website using Mapbox and Blazor. Some questions about this.
Blazor - because I've been using c # for a long time. But on the other hand, so far I have used Javascript to access MapBox:

```html
<script>
     var map = new mapboxgl.Map({ container: 'mapContainer',
     ...
     });
<script>
```

To work with the Map control from MapBox, I would like to make a separate Razor page, where I defined mapContaitner. However, to control, for example, layers visibilities, I need to have access to the map variable.

- is it possible, and if so, how to make it so, that the map variable defined the index.html or -Host.cshtml  is visible from the Razor pages?
- is it better way to  work with the MapBox in .html file or _Host.cshtml using JS, and using Razor pages for other tasks?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question, anyhow, I'll answer what it seems to me to be your question...

If you want to pass values from your _Host.cshtml to the Blazor application, say to the App Component (from which you can cascade it to other parts), you can do the following:

In the App component, define a parameter property to store a value passed from _Host.cshtml, as for instance

```cs
[Parameter]
public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
```

In _Host.cshtml you can do something like this:

```html
<app>
    @{ 
        var val = 120;
    }
    <component param-CurrentCount="@(val)" type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

</app>
```

After your app has been rendered, the property CurrentCount will contain the value 120.

As for your second question... I'm not familiar with MapBox, but I can state here how JavaScript should be used in Blazor:

1. You should have your JavaScript code in the wwwroot folder
2. You should use the OnAfterRenderAsync method to initialize your JavaScript object using JSInterop, as for instance:

```cs
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
            => await JS.InvokeAsync<object>(
                "PinMap.createOrUpdate",
                new object[] { mapElem, new[] { -74.00633, 40.71341 } });
```

3. You can call methods and properties on your object using JSInterop from various part of your application.

   Hope this helps...

Comment: 1. Could you tell  which way is better to cascade  some parameters from app component to other parts (pages)?

Comment: This depends on the design of your app, how your components are designed, and the ease with which they can communicate with each others. There are three methods to do that, and none of which is considered better than others, perhaps more suitable in a given context, but not better. I have already answered questions about the subject in this section. Others did the same. Just search the questions here. Also, I'd recommend to read a blog post from chrissainty about the three methods components can communicate with each others.

Comment: Has this been outdated? Because a simple test doing this results in "InvalidOperationException: Object of type '<applicationname>.App' does not have a property matching the name 'CurrentCount'.

Comment: The challenge is that in the latest, you have to put the parameter in your app.razor file, then figure out how to pass it in the CascadingAuthenticationState object, which routes to your actual first view component.